# Are God and the Lamb the same being? Revelation 22:3-5

Tags: jesus, revelation, attributes-of-god, throne-of-god

Revelation 22:3-5 (ESV) reads:

> 3 No longer will there be anything accursed, but **the throne of God and of the Lamb** will be in it, and **his servants will worship him**. 4 They will see **his face**, and **his name** will be on their foreheads. 5 And night will be no more. They will need no light of lamp or sun, **for the Lord God will be their light**, and they will reign forever and ever.

Verse 3 talks about the throne of God and of the Lamb as two separate entities, but then the following verses use the third-person singular ("he", "his", "him") to address a single being. Are God and the Lamb the same being?

Comment: Colossians 3:1-3 If then you have been raised with Christ, seek the things that are above, where Christ is, seated at the right hand of God.

Comment: The explicit identification of Jesus as the Lamb of God is in John 1:29 and John 1:36, by John the Baptist; the same chapter identifies Jesus as the Son of God and the Word made flesh.  The identification in Revelation is implicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of Revelation 1 shapes how we read of God and His son in the rest of the book. (and impacts how we read of God and His son in the rest of the bible)

> The Revelation of Jesus Christ, which God gave him to show to his bond-servants... 1:1

> The one who overcomes, I will make him a pillar in the temple of my God 3:12

> I will write on him the name of my God, and the name of the city of my God, the new Jerusalem, which comes down out of heaven from my God, and my new name 3:12

> The one who overcomes, I will grant to him to sit with me on my throne, as I also overcame and sat with my Father on His throne 3:21

> I saw in the right hand of Him who sat on the throne a scroll... 5:1
> Stop weeping; behold, the Lion that is from the tribe of Judah, the Root of David, has overcome so as to be able to open the scroll and its seven seals.
> 6 And I saw ... a Lamb standing, as if slaughtered v5-6

What we see quite clearly (and presented very persistently) is a fitting differentiation between God and His son Jesus, the Lamb of God. The risen Jesus, the Lamb, the firstborn of many brothers, still has the same God we do.

With this plain understanding, we can grasp the meaning of other verses that may seem confusing when read alone.

In the passage in question, 22:3 has as the primary subject God (and the Lamb), but the subject is God and the 'His' referred to.

The passage closes with the focus on God as the subject providing the light. Jesus is mentioned in passing through this passage so the 'His' cannot refer to him.

Conclusion:

So the passage must be read in light of other writings by the same author showing that God and the Lamb are not the same being - God is not the Lamb and therefore, the Lamb is not God.

================

Some may use John 10:30 to suggest that *Jesus and the Father are one*. Using proper exegetical process we must not assume this means they are one ‘substance’ or some other fanciful interpretation. To understand what Jesus meant we search other texts to find the answer.

Jesus prayed to his Father regarding the disciples,

> ...so that they may be one as we are one. John 17:11

And repeated again v22

Now we know what John meant in 10:30 - to subscribe to another meaning than *being one in purpose* is to ignore the inspired text interpretation of itself - as God intended.

Comment: What about John 1:1: *In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, **and the Word was God***?

Comment: @Spirit https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54354/does-john-13-identify-jesus-christ-as-the-creator/54928#54928 and https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47927/who-is-the-word-in-john-11/47942?r=SearchResults&s=3|29.0009#47942

Comment: not particularly the highest rated answers ...

Comment: @Spirit just compare to the scriptures and use your own brain. Don't *read in* the nonsense that get touted as truth - Jesus has a God just like us. Either he IS God or he is NOT - we can't have it both ways, DYOR! God bless.

Answer (score 1):

From the very first verse of Rev, John makes a clear distinction between the God the Father and the Son, Jesus Christ.  Here are some examples:

- Rev 1:1 - This is the revelation of **Jesus Christ**, which **God** gave Him to show His servants
- Rev 1:4, 5 - ... from **Him** who is and was and is to come, ... and from **Jesus Christ**, the faithful witness
- Rev 1:5, 6 - To **Him** who loves us and has released us from our sins by His blood, who has made us to be a kingdom, priests to **His God and Father**
- Rev 4, 5 describes the enthronement of the **Lamb** (Jesus) on the right of the throne of the **God**
- Rev 14:1 - Then I looked and saw the **Lamb** standing on Mount Zion, and with Him 144,000 who had His name **and His Father**’s name written on their foreheads.
- Rev 14:4 - They have been redeemed from among men as firstfruits to **God** and to the **Lamb**.

in the case of Rev 22:3, we have:

> καὶ ὁ θρόνος τοῦ Θεοῦ καὶ τοῦ Ἀρνίου (= and the throne of the God and
> of the Lamb)

Grammatically, there is no doubt that this is discussing two different people, "God" and "Lamb" because both have an article (ie, Sharp's rule does not apply.)  Therefore, what is the antecedent of the pronouns later in the same verse, "and **His** servants will worship **Him**"?  Is it God or the Lamb?  If we look earlier we find exactly the same construction, "the throne of the God and the Lamb" - so that is not much help either.

Note the characteristics of the servants in Rev 22:3, 4:

- "his servants serve him" (compare Matt 28:19 - serving Christ; and 2 Cor 3:18, 1 John 3:2 - being like Christ)
- They see his face (contrast John 1:18)
- His name is on their foreheads (compare Rev 14:1 with the Father's name on their foreheads)

Thus, there is little to choose between God and Jesus in the above parallel passages.  The commentaries are similarly vague but perhaps the most helpful is the Pulpit commentary that suggests this:

> But the throne of God and of the Lamb shall be in it; and his servants
> shall serve him; and the throne, etc. This is the consequence of there
> being no accursed thing (cf. Joshua 7:12, 13, "Neither will I be with
> you any more .... There is an accursed thing in the midst of thee, O
> Israel"). God dwells in the city because all is holy. The throne of
> God and of the Lamb is one - God and the Lamb are one. Again, his
> servants, the servants of God and the Lamb (cf. John 10:30). They
> "serve him," as described in Revelation 19:1-7 and elsewhere.
> Revelation 22:3

As noted above, we see the same grammatical problem exists in V1 as well - God and the Lamb are separate people but are referred to here as a single unit.  (Compare Gen 2:24, Eph 5:31, Matt 19:5, Mark 10:8, "the two [married people] shall be one", etc).  That is, while the Father and the Son are separate people, they occupy the same throne and are "one" just as Jesus declared:

> **John 10:30, "I and the Father are one."**

Comment: Dottard....if as you say, Jesus is not God, then neither is the Father. That's clearly impossible for Jesus says in  John 10:30 I and the Father are one.”

31 At this, the Jews again picked up stones to stone Him. 32But Jesus responded, “I have shown you many good works from the Father. For which of these do you stone Me?”

33“We are not stoning You for any good work,” said the Jews, “but for blasphemy, because You, who are a man, declare Yourself to be God.”

Comment: @Adam - I worded that statement carefully and did NOT say Jesus was not God - I said John distinguishes between Jesus and the Father - I agree both are God, but Jesus is NOT the Fathjer and the Father is NOT Jesus.

Comment: This is a good answer. Jesus is fully God, to be sure, and there is one God, but He is not His Father.

Comment: I actually really like this question. It offers an interesting insight into what is God, what is the father, what is the Son. We often read questions asking if Jesus is God, however, has anyone wondered about the question, "is the Father God"? If one answers "yes" to the question of the Father being God, then why should one have an issue with the Son also being God (as an equal with the Father)? It actually explains the Trinity in a single phrased question!

Comment: @Adam The reason one would have a problem is that the Bible teaches that there is only one absolute God, not multiple. The lips of Jesus taught that the Father was the only God (John 5:44, 17:3; Mark 10:18; 12:28-34). This was affirmed by the apostles (1 Timothy 2:5, Romans 3:30; 1 Corinthians 8:4-6; Galatians 3:20).

Comment: @JesusSaves - that all true but that is the difference between your theology and that of the equally explicit declarations of Scripture that Jesus is also God, Matt 1:23, John 1:18, John 5:23, John 10:30, 20:28, Phil 2:5, 6, 1 Tim 3:16, Titus 2:13, Heb 1:8, 2 Peter 1:1, etc.  Thus, there is ONE God but more than one person just as in a marriage there are two people and but one unit, Gen 2:24, Matt 19:6, Mark 10:8, etc.

Comment: Your premise is on disputed verses. Wallace agrees: “Few today with take issue with Rudolf Bultmann’s oft-quoted line that ‘[i]n describing Christ as ‘God’ the New Testament still exercises great restraint.’The list of passages that seem explicitly to identify Christ with God varies from scholar to scholar . . . As is well know, almost all of the texts are disputed as to their affirmation—due to textual or grammatical glitches—John 1:1 and 20:28 being the only two which are usually conceded without discussion. https://bible.org/article/sharp-redivivus-reexamination-granville-sharp-rule

Comment: None of the verses you provided teach that God is a Trinity. If you were consistent ("Jesus is also God") with your premise, you would have to make Moses, angels, and others called "god" in the OT almighty God. You answer has been downvoted.

Comment: @JesusSaves - At no time did I say that God is a trinity - that is your construction in order to justify a downvote.  You have also selectively quoted Wallace.  Please do not put words in my mouth and that of others.  Now, which of the above verses do you dispute?  The fact that even some are beyond dispute proves my case.

Comment: So you are not defending a belief in the Trinity? Please clarify. Wallace admits that most verses used (Jesus is God) are disputed based on grammar and textual problems. None of the verses you provided teach (even the few undisputed) that "there is ONE God but more than one person" as you affirm. All the one God or only God verses that I provided are attributed to the Father. Do you agree with the verses I approved that the Father is the only God? The fact that a few verses call Jesus "god" is consistent with others who spoke and represented God.

Comment: @JesusSaves - your final statement is true of the OT but NEVER in the NT.  Find just one verse that says that a non-transcendental person was "god" and you will have at least some evidence.  Further, None of the verses I quoted have any textual problems - all are undisputed.

Comment: Dear brother @dottard  We can agree to disagree. Follow Jesus to the Father's house (John 14:6).

Comment: @Jesus Saves...Exactly, There is only 1 God. So answer me this, as there is just one God, who are the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit in the Lords prayer (Matthew 6:9)? There cannot be 3 persons that we pray too and yet here we are being told to pray in the names of 3 persons!  The answer is simple...One God, 3 individuals. As a point of interest, in biblehub, do a search for "Lords prayer" and note how often those two words are used together in old testament. Then note how often Jesus is called "Lord" in the New Testament!

Comment: @Adam Dear brother. You wrote, "... yet here we are being told to pray in the names of 3 persons!"  In Mat. 6:9 we are not told to pray in the name of three persons.

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of Revelation (1:8), it says

> 8 “I am the Alpha and the Omega,” says the Lord God, “who is and who was and who is to come, the Almighty.”

And at the end of Revelation (22:13), Jesus says

> 13 I am the Alpha and the Omega, the first and the last, the beginning and the end.

There are several other parallels throughout the Bible that identify Jesus with YHWH (compare Zechariah 12 with John 19, and Isaiah 45 with Philippians 2, etc.), so it would seem reasonable that this passage would allude to it

Comment: I'm sorry, you collapse Jesus into Yahweh. Both Revelation 1:8 and 22:13 describe the Father. What makes you think they refer to Jesus?

Comment: Please read the question again and answer accordingly - you have not mentioned the Lamb at all. Perhaps you can see the link, but the answer is ambiguous.